# How to generate a pdf to a variable instead of a file?

Tags: java, itext, pdf-generation

I am creating a pdf file and storing it in a directory. I now want to pass back the pdf data so the user can download it to their preferred directory (i.e., no longer create the file in the directory). How do I create the "pdfData" to pass back please?

I understand that it would involve replaceing "new FileOutputStream(FILE)" with the name of the variable to store the data in; however, I can not work it out or find an example online.

I have:

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\"+fileName; //Test use
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 72f, 72f, 72f, 72f);
try {
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(FILE));
    document.open();
    addMetaData(document);
    addImages(document);
    addTitlePage(document, recipeDetails, recipeName, servings, servingSize);
    document.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
//return pdfData;
```

Comment: https://api.itextpdf.com/iText5/java/5.5.9/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/PdfWriter.html#getInstance-com.itextpdf.text.Document-java.io.OutputStream-

Comment: Consider using a `ByteArrayOutputStream` instead of the `FileOutputStream` and after closing the document retrieve the byte array from that `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

Comment: Hi Mark, this is where I started. Is there something specific I should look at please (something I missed)?

Comment: Please only call document.close() in a finally clause.. or better yet use the new try-with-resources syntax:

try(Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 72f, 72f, 72f, 72f)) {
    ...
}

Your code has a serious resource leak bug in it.

Comment: Fixed the leak. The ByteArrayOutputStream only returns [B@5b0fc5b7 as the byte array that is retrieved.

Comment: *"only returns [B@5b0fc5b7 as the byte array that is retrieved"* - what you show is the typical `toString` output of a byte array, not the content of it.

Comment: Thank you, I obviously have a lot to learn. So I have looked up how to convert a byte array to an image and am using ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(resourceImage);
  BufferedImage bImage2 = ImageIO.read(bis); and returning bImage2. However, bImage2 is null. I tried returning bis as well; however, that was not in the correct format. I am returning it to the ajax call and downloading with download(responseJson1a['resourseImage'], "resourcefile.pdf", "application/pdf");

Comment: @mkl can you please post your solution so I can accept it. I will raise another post to resolve my decoding issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To show what mkl suggested merged in with your code:

```
String filePath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Documents\\"+fileName; //Test use
Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 72f, 72f, 72f, 72f);
try {
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    PdfWriter.getInstance(document, baos);
    document.open();
    addMetaData(document);
    addImages(document);
    addTitlePage(document, recipeDetails, recipeName, servings, servingSize);
    document.close();

    byte[] pdfData = baos.toByteArray();
    return pdfData;

} catch (Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The pdfData is a byte[] (byte array).  This can be directly streamed/stored anywhere as the actual pdf.  Just keep in mind that this is writing the PDF into memory, so you have scalability issue if doing lots of large PDFs concurrently.

I hope that helps.